# mac terminal scramble lines when editing previous command

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I am using Iterm2 3.3.6 (zsh) and Terminal 2.12.7 application on mac os 12.6.3

When I try to edit previous commands (up) using right-left arrows, the cursor is jumping on some points, and text gets shifted while I am editing.
It is very hard to know where the cursor really is, because it appears on one point and acts at another point.

When I try to adjust the width of the window, the texts gets aligned and looks ok for a moment, but still does not act stable for long, when editing.

I find myself editing commands outside the terminal. what else can I do?

Comment: does your configured terminal emulation align with the terminal set in the `TERM` environment variable? (Output it via `echo $TERM`)

Comment: I can see xterm-256color in my config and $Term

Comment: thats good and bad - good because it eliminates this as potential source of the problem. Bad because of the same reason... ;) - I'm out of clues for now.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had definitions in my .zshrc for tweaking the prompt with date-time and git branch. they worked well with the terminal inside intelij but not so well with others. I removed these and problem was solved